# SwiftUI - HStack NavigationLink "buttons" adding buttonStyle to both elements seperately?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm building my first app and encountering an unclear issue with .buttonStyle within an HStack.

This is my code for the .buttonStyle:

```
struct GradientBackgroundStyle: ButtonStyle {

func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
        .cornerRadius(15.0)
        .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0)
}
```

}

And this is the code in my body:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 15.0) {
            Divider()
            HStack() {
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                    Text("1")
                }.buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle())
        }
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                Text("2")
            }.buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle())
        }
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                Text("Tasks")
            }.buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle())
        }
        Spacer()
    }
        
    .navigationBarTitle(
            Text("Title"))
```

What I am expecting to happen for the third NavigationLink is to see something similar like this:

[Image+text one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ifC.png)

But what I'm getting is this:

[Image+text seperated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN3sv.png)

I've tried fiddling, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You would need a HStack which holds both Image and Text.

```
      HStack {
          NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "star.fill")
              Text("Tasks")
            }
          }.buttonStyle(GradientBackgroundStyle())
      }
```

[image]